# Should I use UILabels?

Tags: ios

I'll start developing a new project and my app will simulate a real machine. This real machine has a screen with approximately 150 mm.

This screen is used to insert data and to show some outputs to the user. It's like those printer's little screen. You know, with some options.

In order to replicate it in my app... Should I use a lot of `UILables`? One per line and column? Or, is there any other way to do it? What's the best practice?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if we look at [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel) we'll see that

> **UILabel**
>
> A view that displays one or more lines of read-only text, often used in conjunction with controls to describe their intended purpose.

So that means that if you want just show some text to the user, `UILabel` is your choice. To be honest, I can't see how it's related to best practices, but if you weren't sure – this is okay to use `UILabel` for your case. You just need to set them up properly.

Comment: Thank you...
The fact is that, once I have multiple lines and column, I'm not sure I'm working with the best tool.

Check how it looks it: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-iBi8F5wufRg/U-ICsEwtrWI/AAAAAAAAI6w/DzEzAzs2BFc/s1600/MANUAL.png

And depending on the system you are seeing, the options and texts will change.

Comment: @BrunoLelli You can set up labels differently. Check the link to the documentation that I've provided. All options and their purposes listed in there with detailed descriptions.

Comment: @BrunoLelli I've checked the image of the interface. You can make it using `NSAttributedString`. It's a very powerful instrument and labels can work with them.

Comment: That's nice Yuri, so, based on what I understood of NSAttributedString, we can create some specific type of strings, with different colors, font type... and while presenting it to the user, you just have to specify what king of text you want, and all the settings will be loaded, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use more than 1 rule in 1 UILabel, by setting the amount of lines in the attribute inspector[image]